# Add a custom Modernizr build to a Gatsby site

Tags: gatsby, modernizr

What's the best way to add a custom Modernizr build to a Gatsby site?

One thought would be to include a `modernizr.js` file in the `static/` folder and then include a script tag importing that file in a layout component. But this doesn't feel like the most Gatsby-friendly approach.

Any other suggestions would be very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

They have an npm package [modernizr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modernizr). Maybe give that a try?

In the `/src/pages/index.js` adding:

```
// Listen to a test, give it a callback
Modernizr.on('testname', function( result ) {
  if (result) {
    console.log('The test passed!');
  }
  else {
    console.log('The test failed!');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your `gatsby-ssr.js`

```
const React = require("react")
export const onRenderBody = ({ setHeadComponents }, pluginOptions) => {
  setHeadComponents([
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>,
  ])
}
```

This will load the Modenizr script and it will be executed